# Can Spring Security ACL support Multi-Tenant?

Tags: java, multi-tenant, spring-security-acl

can I know is Spring Security ACL support Multi-Tenant? I am planning to implement web application with multi-tenant architecture (1 tenant 1 DB). If I would like to use Spring Security ACL with multi-tenant architecture, how spring security ACL load/catch multiple DB ACL_ENTRY? How can i define multiple database in spring security ACL?